# Python modifies newlines when writing a file

Tags: python, file, newline

I am developping a cross platform Python application, and my dev environment is Windows. Due to compatibility issues with previous versions, I have to use Linux-style line endings.

Why is it that this code :

```
lines = ['hello world','bye']
with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

results in CRLF line breaks ?

My Python files are utf-8 encoded, but I don't think this is the issue here.

Is there some way to force Python to use the `\n` line breaks I specified in the strings ?

Comment: Indeed... I didn't find this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When opening a file in text mode, line separators are normalized to the platform default. On Windows, that is `\r\n`. Open a file in binary mode if you do not want this to happen:

```
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
```

On Python 3, you can also set the `newline` keyword to `''` to disabled newline rewriting:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
```